# Freemarker: Calling macro from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I have a freemarker macro like this.

```
<#assign xmlNode = parseXML("<field name='dropDown' type='select' valueName='COUNTRY'/>")>;
    <#import "utilFields.ftl" as util />
     <div>
      <@util.createDropdown field=xmlNode/>
     </div>
```

How would I call the same macro from Javascript?

Tried:

```
<#assign xmlNode = parseXML("<field name='dropDown' type='select' valueName='COUNTRY'/>")>;
<script type="text/javascript">
        var dropdown = "${util.createDropdown(xmlNode)}";
        alert(dropdown);
</script>
```

**Error**

```
FreeMarker template error:
A macro cannot be called in an expression.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to insert the HTML generated by `@util.createDropdown` into the JavaScript string literal. (You can't literally call FreeMarker form JavaScript, since the two run at different times.) The naive approach is just:

```
<#-- Not safe! -->
var dropdown = "<@util.createDropdown field=xmlNode/>";
```

The problem is that `util.createDropdown` writes HTML to the output, and HTML not in general valid as is inside a JavaScript string literal, because you can have `"` in it and so on. You can do a trick like this though:

```
<#macro jsStr>
  <#local captured><#nested></#local>
  "${captured?js_string}"<#t>
</#macro>

...

var dropdown = <@jsStr><@util.createDropdown field=xmlNode/></@>;
```

The `jsStr` macro converts the content printed inside it (and it need not be a single macro call inside it, it can be anything) to a valid JavaScript string literal.